# Unused constant (ACTION_CONFIRM_NOTIFICATION) in Market Billing demo app?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

I'm in the process of implementing in-app billing and I'm using the [Dungeons app](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download) as a reference. There's one thing I don't understand: is `Consts.ACTION_CONFIRM_NOTIFICATION` never actually used? The only place it's referenced is in `BillingService#handleCommand`:

```
if (Consts.ACTION_CONFIRM_NOTIFICATION.equals(action)) {
    String[] notifyIds = intent.getStringArrayExtra(Consts.NOTIFICATION_ID);
    confirmNotifications(startId, notifyIds);
}
```

I *know* that's the only place it's used, I used Eclipse's right click -> references -> project. From what I can tell, that condition is never true: `BillingReceiver` never sends that action and there's no way it could come from anywhere else.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand, ACTION_CONFIRM_NOTIFICATION is never used as this action should be done after you verify a purchase

Comment: So do I. IMHO this is a placeholder for an implementation when you move the verification process to your own server and need to handle response asynchronously, so you have to make it go through receiver.